# Let $A, B, X, Y$ be sets with $X \preccurlyeq A$ and $Y \preccurlyeq B$. Prove that, apart from exceptional case(s), $X^Y \preccurlyeq A^B$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $A, B, X, Y$ be sets with $X \preccurlyeq A$ and $Y \preccurlyeq B$. Prove that, apart from exceptional case(s), $X^Y \preccurlyeq A^B$.

Here, $X \preccurlyeq A$ means there's an injection from $X$ to $A$ etc, and $X^Y$ is the set of functions from $Y$ to $X$ etc.

Presumably the exceptional cases are going to be where some of $A, B, X, Y$ are empty (and I imagine in a proof you'd see exactly where you need certain sets to be non-empty).

I've played around with the injections from $X$ to $A$ and $Y$ to $B$ to try to construct a new one, but I can't seem to find anything that works. Any help you could offer would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, we can try something as follows.
A function is in fact a functional relation, thus
$$
f \in X^Y \Rightarrow f \subset X \times Y; \quad g \in A^B \Rightarrow g \subset A\times B;
$$
such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\forall (x_1; y_1),(x_2; y_2) \in f&: y_1 = y_2 \Rightarrow x_1 = x_2;\\
\forall (a_1; b_1),(a_2; b_2) \in g&: b_1 = b_2 \Rightarrow a_1 = a_2.\\
\end{aligned}
$$

- Consider injections
  $$
  i_X : X \rightarrow A;\quad i_Y : Y \rightarrow B;
  $$
  I can construct mapping
  $$
  i : X \times Y \rightarrow A \times B; \quad
  i: (x,y) \mapsto (i_X(x); i_Y(y)),
  $$
  and check that the mapping is an injection.
  Consider $(x_1;y_1) \neq (x_2;y_2)$, this means $x_1 \neq x_2$ or $y_1 \neq y_2$. 
  Thus we get $i_X(x_1) \neq i_X(x_2)$ or $i_Y(y_1) \neq i_Y(y_2)$.
  Either way we can conclude $(i_X(x_1); i_Y(y_1)) \neq (i_X(x_2); i_Y(y_2))$.
  Worth noting: property of being injective remains if we restrict $X \times Y$ to any subset.
- Now consider mapping
  $$
  I: P(X \times Y) \rightarrow P(A \times B)
  $$
  that acts as follows
  $$
  \forall S \in P(X \times Y): I(S) = \{i(s)| s\in S\}.
  $$
  Now I claim $I$ is an injection.
  Consider $S_1 \neq S_2$, which means one of them contains at least one element, say $s$, that the other does not.
  Without loss of generality suppose $s \in S_1$ and $s \notin S_2$.
  Using injectivity of $i$ we get
  $$
  s \notin S_2 \rightarrow \forall s' \in S_2: s' \neq s
  \rightarrow \forall s' \in S_2: i(s') \neq i(s)
  \rightarrow i(s) \notin I(S_2),
  $$
  which means $I(S_1) \neq I(S_2)$, thus $I$ is injective.
- Now we know that $I$ maps relations injectively.
  The only unsolved problem is whether it does not "destroy" the property "to be a function".
  If not -- we are done here as we found an injection from functions $X^Y$ to $A^B$.
  So let's prove this property.
  Since $i_Y$ is an injection and $(x;y) \in f$, where $f$ is a function
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  \forall (i_X(x); i_Y(y)) \in A \times B: i_Y(y_1) = i_Y(y_2) \Rightarrow y_1 = y_2 \Rightarrow\\
  \Rightarrow x_1 = x_2 \Rightarrow i_X(x_1) = i_X(x_2).
  \end{aligned}
  $$
  The latter is true for any subset of $A \times B$, thus $I$ is injection from functions $X^Y$ to functions $A^B$.